# Erro HTTP 500 ao colocar um projeto laravel5.1 em produção

Tags: php, laravel-5

Desenvolvi um projeto em Laravel 5.1.No Localhost funciona tudo certo, mas quando subo para o servidor do cliente, que não é compartilhado e está com PHP 5.6, não funciona.
Aparece o erro `HTTP ERROR 500`.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Só olhando no log do PHP, se tiver cpanel de uma olhada, mas provavelmente faltou alguma extensão ser ativada ou a versão do php é mais antiga que o 5.6. Só o log pra ter certeza

Comment: No Log ta falando que o problema está no index.php nessas 2 linhas
       require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

       app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

Comment: Coloca o erro na pergunta da exata maneira que esta escrito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema que eu segue ai como consegui resolver.

Criei um arquivo **.htaccess** com o seguinte código.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meusite.com.br$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www. meusite.com.br$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Sem precisar alterar mais nada.

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente isso ocorre porque em `Produção` o erro está desativado.

**O erro da Página em branco**

Se estiver aparecendo apenas uma página em branco ou `Erro 500`, eu gosto fazer os seguintes testes:

```
> php artisan
```

Ou então

```
> php public/index.php
```

Se por exemplo estiver aparecendo apenas "uma página em branco", o erro que está gerando ela aparecerá na linha de comando ao executar os testes acima.

**Dependências não instaladas**

Outra coisa que deve ser avaliada são as `dependências`.
Se você estiver o `GIT` como eu para controlar as alterações do servidor, geralmente optará por deixar a pasta `vendor` ignorada no repositório. Então nesse caso, você deve executar o comando `composer install`, caso em seu ambiente ainda não contiver a pasta `vendor`. Em outros casos, é sempre bom usar o `composer dump -o`.

** Log de erros**

Outra coisa é que, em ambiente de produção, é sempre bom você deixar os erros desativados. Caso queira saber o problema ocorrido em produção, você pode consultar o  log de erros do laravel.

O log fica no seguinte caminho:

```
 app/storage/logs/laravel.log
```